# Updater method updating from keyboard input doesn't like method calls?

Tags: java, class, keylistener

I am back again.

I am trying to have a box that moves with keyboard commands, but it does not seem to be working how it should. Here is the code:

Game Class

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Game extends Applet
{
    Thread loopThread;
    boolean left  = false;
    boolean right = false;
    boolean up = false;
    boolean down = true;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int tick = 0;
    int[][] board = new int[12][12];
    Graphics g;
    Player p = new Player(0,0);

    public void run() 
    { 

        long startTime;

        if (loopThread == null) 
        {
            loopThread = new Thread();
            loopThread.start();
        }


        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(Thread.currentThread() == loopThread) 
        {
            update(g);
        }
    }


    public void update(Graphics g) 
    {

         System.out.println("repaint");
         if(left)
         {
             p.goL();
             p.drawPlayer();
             left = false;
         }
         else if(right)
         {
             p.goR();
             p.drawPlayer();
             right = false;
         }
         else if(up)
         {
             p.goU();
             p.drawPlayer();
             up = false;
         }
         else if(down)
         {
             p.goD();
             p.drawPlayer();
             down = false;
         }
         else
         {
             p.drawPlayer();
         }

    }


    public boolean keyDown(Event e, int key) 
    {
            if (key == Event.LEFT) {
                left = true;
            }

            if (key == Event.RIGHT) {
                right = true;
            }

            if (key == Event.UP) {
                up = true;
            }

            if (key == Event.DOWN) {
                down = true;
            }

            repaint();
            return true;
     }
}
```

Player Class

```
  import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Event;
    import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Player
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int[][] b;
    Graphics g;

    public Player(int xPos, int yPos)
    {
        int x = xPos;
        int y = yPos;
    }

    public void drawPlayer()
    {
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));
        g.fillRect(40*x, 40*y, 40, 40);
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public void goL()
    {
        x--;
    }

    public void goR()
    {
        x++;
    }

    public void goU()
    {
        y++;
    }

    public void goD()
    {
        y--;
    }

}
```

I had it working before when I put the drawing methods inside of the if statements in the update class (and I can still put drawing methods inside there and they trigger when the corresponding keys are pressed), but when I try to reference a method in a different class that draws, it seems to be unresponsive. I am not sure if there is an issue with the update method and key commands (that is new to me), or if there is something fundamentally wrong with my Player class that makes work as intended.

Any input is helpful, Thanks! (Also, I want to use Applet, not Jframe, it is a preference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you change the `drawPlayer` method to this:

```
public void drawPlayer(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));
    g.fillRect(40*x, 40*y, 40, 40);
}
```

and then just pass the `Graphics` object from the `Game` class like this:

```
public void update(Graphics g) 
{
     System.out.println("repaint");
     if(left)
     {
         p.goL();
         p.drawPlayer(g);
         left = false;
     }
     else if(right)
     {
         p.goR();
         p.drawPlayer(g);
         right = false;
     }
     else if(up)
     {
         p.goU();
         p.drawPlayer(g);
         up = false;
     }
     else if(down)
     {
         p.goD();
         p.drawPlayer(g);
         down = false;
     }
     else
     {
         p.drawPlayer(g);
     }

}
```

The box should draw. Although, for some reason, I had to click the `Applet` first for it to start drawing and then if you resize the `Applet`, the drawing goes away.

Also, as a simple fix for if you don't want a trail of the previous box positions, just create two variables to keep track of the previous box position and then clear it. For example:

```
private int lastX;
private int lastY;

public void drawPlayer(Graphics g)
{
    g.clearRect(40*lastX, 40*lastY, 40, 40);
    g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));
    g.fillRect(40*x, 40*y, 40, 40);
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
}
```